# How can I populate a page with AJAX generated HTML before JQuery applies functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I can't get the jQuery Mobile functionality to apply after I have populated the schedule `div` with the AJAX generated HTML containing `data-role` elements. I've tried reordering things, including putting the script in the body tag, to no avail.  Is there a way to force the jQuery to run after my AJAX?

`schedule.html:`

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="../javascript/agenda.js"></script>
    <script> loadSchedule(); </script>
    <script src="../javascript/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../javascript/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
  </head>
<body>
  <div id="schedule"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

`agenda.js:`

```
function loadSchedule(){
  text = "...LOTS OF AJAX HTML GENERATION...";
  document.getElementById("schedule").innerHTML = text;
}
```

*Apologies ahead of time as I'm a total noob with JS.*

Comment: You could do it, via: http://requirejs.org/

Comment: jQuery's ajax function has an `async: false` option, which I believe would do what you're looking for, but that would probably be a lousy user experience since it would lock up the screen and probably take longer to load the page.

Comment: Why do you need the jquery to load after loadSchedule()? You can use **$.ajax** from jquery to do what you're doing in basic javascript there.

Comment: If you move all your `<script>` to the end of the `<body>` then first agenda.js will be loaded, then loadSchedule() will execute, and after all that jquery files will load. That is what you requested. Or you have AJAX in agenda.js? Then you'd add srcipt tags for jQuery as plain html to the end on body in your AJAX callback (success function)

Comment: look into the `refresh` methods in jQuery mobile

Comment: To clarify, `loadSchedule()` generates all the HTML to be used and the page becomes Static at that point.  There are http://api.jquerymobile.com/popup/ thoughout the generated HTML as `<a href="#popupBasic" data-rel="popup">Open Popup</a> <div data-role="popup" id="popupBasic">...</div>` that don't work properly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question exactly but it sounds like you are having trouble applying JQuery events to dynamic content. JQuery handles dynamic content through the .on function which basically retroactively applies your binding to all newly created DOM elements that match your selector.

JQuery docs link:
http://api.jquery.com/on/

Usage example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").on('click', '#my_new_div', function() {
        // this event is fired when clicking on div#my_new_div even if it is dynamically created
    });
});
```

Hope this helps!